# Cant add solution to RocketSvn Repositories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to set up RocketSVN server on win server 2008 R2 and the plug in client for Visual studio's 2010 but have been have a lot of trouble so will list what i have had issues with and what i did to get them working and where i am up to.

First I was having trouble connecting to the server through a browser which came down to the fact that i hadn't installed the Basic and windows Authentication on the server IIS features Doh! (fresh install :)) although it still didn't work until i went through the windows updates, After these steps i could connect to the Admin portal through a browser add add repositories and users yay! 
Then i moved on to the Visual Studio's plugin and was having trouble being authenticated while trying to add or open a project from svn so back to Google and found a solution here http://community.axosoft.com/forums/thread/22088.aspx but was not using windows authentication which i wanted and was now getting another issue, I found that changing the binding in the IIS to HTTPS and setting a certificate let me use windows authentication and got me to the same position but now I'm stuck again....

tried to add images but wont let me Grrrr.... Edit : I can add images now :)

every time i try to add a solution i don't get a folder to save it to and the "Create Folder" button is greyed out all i get is the

1. Subversion Repositories
2. https://`<server name>`:8080
   [image]

so am missing the svn/testrep/(testrep being my repository) folder to select and add my solution to..

I am using the repository URL found on the admin portal..
[image]

The error i get if i try and open a solution (even though i don't have any solutions in the repository i thought i might be able to browse it?) is
"server sent unexpected return value (405 not allowed) in response to propfind"
[image]

i hope some body can help me with this as I'm losing the will to live with this one :( i thinking its still a server set up issue but cant find any more info let my no if any 1 wants to see any server logs / config's / settings.

Cheers in advance